# Unix move all files from home directory into another folders

Tags: unix

I accidentally outputted 20k .txt files into my home directory, is there any Unix commands to move all those files into another directory?

Comment: There is even a Wikipedia page for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mv

Comment: `mv` might fail if there are too many arguments.  Ex. `mv * newdirectory` might fail.  If that happens, you can use `find` with the `-exec` option to `mv` the files.

Comment: When your homedir already had files before you outputted the files, you do not want to move all files. Perhaps you can start moving all files created the last 2 days, check the results and move some back. `mkdir $HOME/accident; find $HOME -type f -mtime -2 -exec mv {} $HOME/accident\; `